# Copy and paste localStorage data to clipboard on click

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

So let's say i have data in localStorage and there's 25 different names. How do i copy and paste that localStorage data via clipboard by clicking buttons.

This is the code of button that needs to copy localStorage data:

`<a href="" onclick="copyjson()"><div id="Shape1"><div id="Shape1_text"><span style="color:#303C49;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;"><strong>Скопировать данные</strong></span></div></div></a>`

I tried to copy using js code, but somehow it only run if i run that through console:

```
function copyjson() {
    copy(JSON.stringify(localStorage));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```js
async function copyContent() {
  try {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      JSON.stringify(localStorage)
    );
    console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    /* Resolved - text copied to clipboard successfully */
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
    /* Rejected - text failed to copy to the clipboard */
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Also i had to allow clipboard in browser

Comment: could you please add function for pasting this clipboard to localStorage?

Comment: Same way with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText

`let text = navigator.clipboard.readText()` as @kahveciderin say.

Answer (score 0):

The `copy` function is only used for debugging on console, and isn't actually a function that you can use in scripts (you will see that if you try to access it via `window.copy`).

Take a look at the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) and specifically to the .write method.